# Does stretching before exercise raise the risk of injury?

Tags: sport, physical-fitness

> [Robert McLeod](http://entropyproduction.blogspot.de/2012/12/why-stretching-is-bad-for-you.html): Pulling on a muscle for a long time doesn't make it longer, doesn't make it more pliable, and doesn't improve athletic performance. There's lots of scientific literature that shows that stretching before exercise increases the risk of injury, but still there's a lot of emphasis on it in common fitness literature.

Is that true? Is the scientific consensus that the stretching before exercise that a lot of fitness literature recommends increases the risk of injury?

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/is-stretching-beneficial-after-exercise (Duplicate? Answer seems to cover this.)

Comment: Related: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/470